# MVC Validation input-validation-error CSS not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

morning

i can't get the input-validation-error css to work when i have a class already for the input box.

```
<%=Html.TextBox("FirstName", null, new { @Class = "text" })%>
<%=Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName", new { @style = "color: red;", @Class = "errorInValid" })%>
```

if i take out new { @Class = "text" } then

```
.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
    background-color: red !important;     
}
```

The above CSS works.

Help

regards,
pete

thanks in advance (i am crap at CSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer but try checking the order of how classes get applied in the css.

input-validation-error usually renders before any other classes like

```
<input type="text" class="input-validation-error text-box single-line">
```

try putting it at the end in firebug and see if something changes - probably it get's overwritte by another rule.

Don't know how your .text class is defined - you could also try to define **.input-validation-error** as **form .input-validation-error** so it automatically gains higher importance.

This is definately a cascade problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add both .input-validation-error and .input.input-validation-error classes.